# Noflo vs node-red vs totaljs

Tags: node-red, noflo, total.js

What's the major difference between all three and what makes noflo stand out over the rest?

I couldn't find anyone who made a comparison between them

Comment: Please read the SO doc about the type of questions to avoid asking (as they will be closed) https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 4):

I hardly think that you are looking for a fair comparison since you seem to have pre-selected your choice.

Also, trying to compare Node-RED and NoFlo with Total.js makes no sense. You are comparing flow-based tools against something different.

As an active contributor to Node-RED, you would expect me to say that it is best - and I will!

If I remember rightly, there is either no GUI for editing flows in NoFlo or it is a paid-for option? Not sure, a long time since I looked at it.

Node-RED is true open-source, part of the JavaScript Foundation, has active support from IBM and Hitachi as well has a very strong and welcoming community. It has many contributors to the core, add on nodes and documentation.

It has an excellent administration/programming GUI and several ways of creating user GUI's. ...

Comment: Thanks, I was asking a question on the noflo site that directed me here, I'm leaning towards node red for streaming pricing data for trading and run the algorithm 24/7. I hired a programmer but need to decide if node red or is it noflo that can handle the job and do while loops. I read some where or noflo presentation that node red is a data management rather than programming with complex loops, and if statements

Comment: Node-RED is excellent for prototyping process automation. Many people use it for IoT and run complex, custom home automation systems using it. It won't necessarily be as efficient as well-written code but it can make it a lot easier to prototype your logic flow.

Comment: I use Node-Red in production environnement ( although you need to pay attention to security issue, once that done properly, node-red work fast and for a long time, 160 days without any kind of reboot requirements ). I use it for IoT and it does stand 450k msg/s in burst mode and 80k msg/s in regime mode. I would say the main differences lie in the fact node-red force a tcp/ip socket to be open and won't work without.

Comment: @danbo thanks for these comments, very helpful. +1 for mentioning security, a rather hot topic for me. It would be great to find a place to collate some performance stats for Node-RED, would you like to drop into the [Node-RED forum](https://discourse.nodered.org) and create a topic so that we can discuss it?